# C# Sending Email using SMTP E-mail

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, smtp

I'm rather new to SMTP and IIS settings but according to the documentation on I've read the web this should be working.

**What I'm trying to achieve:**
To send an email from the server to a users email using an existing SMTP Relay Server.

**What I have done:**
In my IIS, for my site (ASP.NET), I have configured the SMTP E-mail.
I have entered:

1. A random E-mail address (it doesn't have to be an existing, right?)
2. A SMTP Server IP (in this case an IP to an external SMTP Relay Server)
3. A port number (25).
4. Autentication Settings to "Not required".

My method for sending an email looks like this:

```
public static void SendEmail()
{
    var message = new MailMessage()
    {
        Subject = "Heading",
        Body = "Body",

        message.From = new MailAddress("test@test.com");
        message.To.Add("A valid email address"); //My own email address
    }
    var smtpClient = new SmtpClient("SMTP-Relay-Server-IP", 25); //Same IP as the one in SMTP E-mail configuration in IIS for the site.         
    smtpClient.Send(message);
}
}
```

**Facts/questions:**

1. Is this correct? Is it correct to also put the Relay Server IP and Port number in the code as parameters in the new `SmtpClient`?
2. I don't get an error but I don't receive an email. (I am 100% sure that the "to-email" is correct.
3. What can be the reason for this not working? What am I missing or misunderstanding?

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your `smtpClient.Send(message);` in a try/catch block and log any exceptions that are thrown.

> A random E-mail address (it doesn't have to be an existing, right?)

That depends on your SMTP provider and configuration.

Without more information on your SMTP provider or an error message I doubt there's anything we can do for you.

Comment: Have tried, no exceptions are thrown which indicates that it seems to work without errors.

Comment: @ChrisRun Check your SMTP for errors. It could be there's something wrong with the SMTP preventing the email from being sent. What is your SMTP provider? Is it a locally hosted exchange server?

Comment: There are no SMTP errors, but I was able to find out that all my sent emails are being sent to C:\inetpub\mailroot\Queue as .EML files. If i open them they contain the correct subject, body and even to-address.

Comment: If the messages are being queued, but not sent, then I would assume that the SMTP server is unable to send the messages. Check your log files.

Answer (score -2):

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("sendTo", "from");
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass");
smtp.Port = 25;
smtp.EnableSsl = true;
smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
mail.Body = "this my message";
smtp.Send(mail);
```

should be set out like this

Comment: how do you know the SMTP is gmail? The OP said anonymous authentication was set, which can't be configured in gmail, so there's no need to set network credentials. Port 25 wouldn't even work for gmail anyways. You haven't even told the OP what he could be doing wrong, and it looks like you haven't even tried to analyse the problem.